# Using Lumetri HSL secondary mask to create alpha transparency

Tags: mask, premiere-pro

How can I use the selection made using the Lumetri HSL Secondary Set Color tool to define alpha transparency. That is to say: how can I use my Lumetri colour selection to create a transparency mask to reveal the color matte on the layer below? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set Lumetri to reveal the sections of your clip that you want. (In the example shown, I have also inverted the mask).

Click the "Show Mask" checkbox in the 'HSL Secondary' section of the Lumetri plugin.  All the parts that are not selected by your 'HSL secondary' settings will appear grey in the viewer window.

[image: screen2]

On the same clip, add the Ultra Key plugin so that it appears beneath your Lumetri plugin.

In the Ultra Key, set the Key Colour using the paint dropper to the same shade of grey that appears in the greyed out areas of your clip.
[image: screen]

Those sections of your clip are now transparent.

To check, click the wrench icon below the viewer, and enable 'transparency grid'
[image: wrench]

Comment: Thanks, but I think you might have a missed a step or have a switch on (or off!) by default that I don't have, but this doesn't work for me. I set the key colour to the grey, using the eye dropper but nothing happens and the underlying layer is not revealed.

Comment: hmm odd.. Is the Ultra Key effect definitely below the Lumetri effect in the effects list for the clip?